# SQL запрос с множественным условием

Tags: mysql, sql, golang

Хочу сделать запрос что то вроде:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable Where id = 1 AND id = 2 AND ...
```

В коде это дело выглядит так:

```
rows, err := tx.NamedQuery(
    `
    SELECT * FROM someTable
    WHERE
        someTable.id = :id;
    `,
    struct {
        ID int `db:"id"`
    }{
        ID: 5,
    },
)
```

Немогу придумать, как мне сделать так, чтобы в случае если мне понадобится информация по рандомному количеству юзеров, то как тогда все это подставить, так чтобы отсечь иньекции.

Comment: А нельзя писать так? `SELECT * FROM someTable Where id IN (...)`?

Comment: `Where id = 1 AND id = 2` Вы правда хотите найти запись, у которой id равно одновременно и единице, и двойке? Наверное, OR будет разумнее...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271123/how-to-execute-an-in-lookup-in-sql-using-golang

Comment: Насчет AND простите ошибся, действительно там OR! 
Насчет IN это дельный совет, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я в своем коде использовал библиотеку `database/sql` и вот так имплементировал в код `db.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username) FROM users`